# Android: My app become slow and not responding after use custom textview in grid view

Tags: android, unicode, textview

This is my custom `TextView` with unicode render. It's work fine. But when I use this custom `TextView`  with grid view that have many cell my application become slow and not responding.
How can I fix this?

```
public class KhmerTextView extends TextView { 

 KhmerRender kr;

    public KhmerTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setTypeFace(getText().toString());
    }

    public KhmerTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setTypeFace(getText().toString());
    }

    public KhmerTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        setTypeFace(getText().toString());
    }

    public void setTypeFace(String text) {
        kr = new KhmerRender();
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "Roboto-Condensed.ttf");

        if (kr.isUnicode(text) ) {
            tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "NokorKhmer.ttf");

        }
        setTypeface(tf);

    }

    public void setKhmerText(String text) {
        setTypeFace(text);
        if (kr.isUnicode(text)) {
            super.setText(kr.renderKhmer(text));
        }
        else {
            super.setText(text);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: perhaps you could provide the TypeFace from a static resource, so it does not get loaded every time? Just a hint

Comment: How can? Can you show me an example, please?

Comment: whats KhmerRender? are u using asyntasks?

Comment: No KhmerRender is simple class for render Khmer Unicode Character

Comment: have you tried it without the render? think this could also be slowing down everything

Comment: Do you get something useful in the logcat? Did you check if you have an infinite loop which causes the ANR?